# Making Formulas more dynamic when dragged across the sheet

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, count, substitution

Here is a [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1G7Hsv_KklrIDpI2_GedUL-f5MbgPEmOstd5miDudyVs/edit?usp=sharing) to a sample of my sheet.

Columns B and C work well,  despite how clunky the functions are. I would like to make the functions in any cell B2:C7 more dynamic, and am using column D as a testing column. I am not a fan of how INDIRECT() needs to be manually changed when dragging the cells across and am looking for a simpler solution.

Specifically looking at the INDEX() function in cell D2.

I am trying to run a counta(D7:the row with today's date) in cell D2.

When I do

```
=(counta(D7:D13))/365
```

I get the correct result 6/365 = 1.644.

Now, when I use the INDEX() to call on the value in CELL D3 as shown here:

```
=(counta(D7:INDEX(D:D,3,)))/365
```

I get a value which would match the 4/365 = 1.096

When I highlight "INDEX(D:D,3,)" the tool tip pops up and shows the correct value of cell D3 which is "D13"

Another user provided a working solution using INDIRECT() and SUBSTITUTE, but **I am specifically curious about why INDEX() acts this way as it seems to be much simpler to read/understand.** Any reason why its off by 2 values?

Thanks,

Comment: what is the actual goal here?  That is, are you just looking for simple formulas to tell you the longest streak? the current streak? and the streak break at?

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion. I'm not worried about the streaks atm, as those work. My primary goal is to simplify my functions in row 2 and then extrapolate what I learn from everyone here to apply those methods down the road. B2 and C2 (copy of B2), work, but those need to be manually changed each time a column (like C and now D) is added. To circumvent this, I decided to forgo the INDIRECT() as it's getting messy and go with INDEX(). Cell D2 is to giving an incorrect value and I would like to know why the INDEX() method doesn't work for this scenario. Thanks! Hope I was able to clarify my ?

Comment: what is the purpose of row 2 though is what I'm asking?

Comment: Apologies! Its a progress tracker for the year. Total days of habit completed (eg days not missed)/365. End goal is for each column to be as close to 100% complete as possible.

Comment: could you make the sample sheet editable instead of view only so people can test/demonstrate ideas?

Comment: Taken care of, sir

Comment: it'd be awesome if you could leave a copy of the sheet up as View Only so that others in the future might learn from it.  Stack is supposed to be mostly a resource rather than a help desk.

Comment: Ah, sorry. meant to restrict back to viewer but changed it to restricted by habit. Thanks for the heads up! Fixed again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED:
After understanding the question a little better...

Here is a formula to show the percent complete that can be dragged sideways, you can find it on the new tab called MK.Help:

```
=COUNTIFS($A7:$A,"<="&TODAY(),B7:B,"<>")/365
```